# Player position jumps when moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to implement a circular movement for my player. It works perfectly, but the only problem I have is when the movement state is first entered, the player position jumps to a position on the y axis, horizontally aligned to the `centerofgravity` transform position.

After that it works fine though and the player can move around the circle as expected.

How can I set the `transform.position` to start at the players current position, instead of jumping to center of gravity's y position.

```
    private void MovePlayerInACircle() {
        player.SetVelocityX(playerDataSO.movementVelocity * xInput);
        currentVelocityX = player.CurrentVelocity.x;

        player.rotationDirection += Time.deltaTime * currentVelocityX;

        float x = Mathf.Cos(player.rotationDirection) * player.distToCenterOfGravity;
        float y = Mathf.Sin(player.rotationDirection) * player.distToCenterOfGravity;
        float z = 0f;

        player.transform.position = player.centerOfGravity + new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }
```